# Multicolor Text Highlighting in a Textarea or Text Input

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to set text in a textarea or text input using different colors (one or the other is fine, I don't need both).  Think of something like simple syntax highlighting. So, let's say I have some keywords defined.  I'd like those words to be colored a different color as the user types into the textarea or text input

I understand this needs to be some combination of CSS, Javascript, and maybe some pixie dust.  I wondering which direction I need to dig into to find out how this can be done.

Thank you

Comment: On what criteria do you want any particular portion of text to have a different colour?

Comment: I would identify certain keywords ahead of time, and would like to change their color as the user is typing.  Similar to how syntax highlighting works in an IDE.

Comment: alternative example in here http://stackoverflow.com/a/33588043/257319 (using CSS and no inline-style)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

No, you can't do this in a textarea or text input. Any CSS text-related property will affect the whole text within the the textarea/input. You'll need an editable element or document to achieve syntax highlighting. Example (works in all recent browsers; the last major browser not to support `contenteditable` was Firefox 2.0):

```html
<code contenteditable="true">
  <span style="color: blue">var</span> foo = <span style="color: green">"bar"</span>;
</code>
```

Comment: Your answer is not 100% right. It is possible to change textarea properties using javascript as thats the way [codemMirror](http://codemirror.net/) has done it. Look at their example code to see how they did it

Comment: @user1951751: No, the main edit area in CodeMirror is not a textarea. You can read more about it here: http://marijnhaverbeke.nl/blog/browser-input-reading.html. Admittedly my answer doesn't mention the CodeMirror approach (regular div and pre elements for the editor, fake caret, hidden textarea for user input).

Comment: @TimDown Interesting, didn't notice that just from the code, thanks for the link

Comment: You don't need to assign a value to some attributes, which includes ContentEditable. `<code contentEditable>` will work as well.

Comment: @Arjun: That is true. However, I prefer to be explicit and provide the value, particularly on SO, because `contenteditable` isn't a Boolean attribute. Its allowed values are "true", "false" and "inherit".

Comment: @Arjun: It was required however in XHTML. In HTML 5 maybe not so.

Comment: This is an old answer, but I wanted to ask if there is any difference between using <code> and <div>? Both allow contenteditable

Comment: @MysteryPancake: There's no significant difference except for default style properties for the respective elements (e.g. `<code>` is by default inline, `<div>` is block, `<code>` defaults to monospace font, `<div>` doesn't).

Answer (score 1):

Are you finding this?

Use jQuery.colorfy

Code:
https://github.com/cheunghy/jquery.colorfy

Demo:
http://cheunghy.github.io/jquery.colorfy/

Screencast:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b1Lu_qKrLZ0

Comment: this is not maintained anymore, use this: https://lonekorean.github.io/highlight-within-textarea/

Answer (score -2):

This can actually be done by using styling inside of the tag, this is a reference from one of my websites where i have done this

```
<input style="border-radius: 5px; background-color: #000000; color: #ff0000; border-color:
 blue;" class="form-control" name="firstname" placeholder="What you were looking for?"
 type="text"
 required autofocus />
```

Comment: This doesn't satisfy the asker's condition of:
"I'd like those words to be colored a different color **as the user types** into the textarea or text input"