# Color text to some fixed limit when I type

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a textarea. And I am not using any plugin and or API. Implemented the word count that the count increase/decrease when I type.

Basically I want to award points. Say 20 Points if he types in 50 words.
**I want** that whatever user types the text gets colored but only till 50 words after that words can be black itself.

Means text gets colored while I type till 50 words and remains of same color but remaining words must be normal

**JS**

```
$('#content').keyup(function(){
    var wordCount = $(this).val().split(' ').length;
    if(wordCount <= 50){
        $(this).css('color', 'green');
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you got any existing html, or any JavaScript/jQuery that you're working with? Have you made any attempts so far?

Comment: By [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3435167/is-it-possible-to-have-several-different-textcolors-in-one-textarea) and [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845813/multicolor-text-highlighting-in-a-textarea-or-text-input), it seems that textarea don't support what you want.

Comment: Thomas, I did this (updated question), I realize what is happening here but unable to help myself.

Comment: @AshwaniGoyal try using a contenteditable div and on the keyup event just check the length of the text and wrap it in a colored span if it is more than 50 characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works pretty well in Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari, and IE11 (at least).

It overlays a `div` on the `textarea`, making sure both elements have the same CSS.  A number of CSS properties are important to make this possible, especially `word-wrap: pre-wrap`, which allows the `div` to handle multiple spaces correctly.

Using `-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;` allows the `textarea` to display a cursor while making its text invisible.  This works in webkit browsers only, but it doesn't kill the functionality in other browsers.  In IE, the text is simply darker because it shows the `div`'s text overlaid on top of the `textarea`'s.

Finally, adding `pointer-events: none;` to the `div` allows you to position the mouse on the `textarea` that's behind it.

For the purposes of the snippet, I've set the word count to 5 instead of 50.

**Snippet:**

```js
$('textarea').on('input', function() {
  var word = 0,
    lastLetter;

  $('#output > span').text('');
  this.value.split('').forEach(function(letter, i) {
    if (letter === ' ' && lastLetter !== ' ') word++;
    lastLetter = letter;
    if (word < 5) {
      $('#output span:first').append(letter);
    } else {
      $('#output span:last').append(letter);
    }
  });
});

$('textarea').focus();
```

```css
textarea,
#output {
  width: 500px;
  height: 10em;
  padding: 0.2em;
  margin: 0.2em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font: 13px arial;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
textarea {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  overflow: auto;
}
#output {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 1;
}
#output span:first-of-type {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output"><span></span><span></span></div>
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: Rick, I must say Hats Off to you buddy. So very cool and nice explanation. thumbs up :)

Comment: Thanks.  Now tested in Firefox, Safari, and Opera, so it should be safe to use on a live site.

Comment: Input event now cleaned up using the excellent regex from @JosephMarikle 's answer.

Comment: Heyy Rick, I think you should share the prior JS too, as it was more relevant to my query and dynamic as well. This contains regex that would restrict us to go with static value always.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're using jQuery at least.
I created a fiddle for you http://jsfiddle.net/fdp1f715/ and a snippet :)
Is this what you want?

```js
$(function () {
    $('textarea#foo').on('keyup', function () {
        var content = $(this).val();
        var n = content.split(" ").length; // get number of words 
        $('p#nOfWords').text(n); // print number of words        
        $(this).removeClass('bar');
        if (n > 50) {
            $(this).addClass('bar');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
textarea {
    color: black;
}
textarea.bar {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="foo"></textarea>
<p id="nOfWords"></p>
```

Comment: Yes ofcourse I am using jQuery. YOur solution to what I am stuck with. I need words colored while I type and color stops after 50 words.

Answer (score 1):

You could replace the contents with the contents having the first 50 words wrapped in a span.  This means it has to be outside of an input field though.  In any case, here's my stab at it (note that my demo limits to 3 words for demonstration purposes.  Change `{0,3}` to `{0,50}` for 50):

```js
$('textarea').on('input', function(){
    $('.output').html(this.value.replace(/(([^\s]+\s*){0,3})(.*?)/, '<span>$1</span>$3'));
});
```

```css
span {color:green}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="output"></div>
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: Joseph, I can see the progress but I need it happening in the textarea itself instead of `.output`. I have decided to go with div with contenteditable = "true" but still no luck

Comment: I posted a complicated input event function yesterday, and now I see your beautiful regex.  I hope you don't mind me borrowing it for my answer.

Comment: @RickHitchcock I don't mind at all.  Fantastic solution btw.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that. Here a vanilla javascript solution: http://jsfiddle.net/afhmpc4q/2/

```
<textarea id="area"></textarea>
```

JS

```
var checktext = {
    "check": function () {
        var words = this.value.match(/\S+/g).length;
        if (words > 10) {
            this.style.color = "red";
            alert("over limit");
        }
    }
};

var areatocheck = document.getElementById("area");
areatocheck.onkeyup = checktext.check;
```