# How to color part of an input field of a wtform flask

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am developing a flask app. I have a flask form and I am trying to color only part of an input field. The idea is that I would get two indices that will represent the start and end of the substring in an input field that I need to color.

My code is as follows:

The `inputField`:

```
review = TextAreaField('Review', validators=[DataRequired()])
```

The HTML:

```
<p>
    {{ form.prompt.label }}<br>
    {{ form.prompt(size=32) }}
</p>
```

Using Chrome's inspector (Ctrl + Shift + I):

```
<p>
    <label for="review">Review</label><br>
    <textarea id="review" name="review" required="" size="32">This is a test case</textarea>
</p>
```

The JavaScript function:

```
<script>
    var label = document.getElementById('review');
    var sub = label.innerHTML;
    label.innerHTML = label.innerHTML.replace(sub.substring(0,2), '<span style="color:red;">'+sub.substring(0,2) '+'</span>');
</script>
```

This function however does not style the text. It instead fills the text box with

```
"<span style="color:red;">'+sub.substring(0,2) '+'</span>".
```

What would be a good way to resolve this issue?

Comment: Colouring part of a string of an input field is not trivial. Here is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45233743/javascript-how-to-change-color-to-only-part-of-the-string-in-an-input-field) which does exactly what you want JS-wise. I'd reconsider if you really need this feature.

Comment: That answer predefines the number of spans we would need. In my case, I might need to color multiple portions of the text. It depends on the output of the function that provides me indices and colors. It would give me a list of lists where each list shows the start index, end index and the color. So there could be multiple regions of the text I would need to color. It depends on what the user enters in the input field.