# <code contenteditable="true"> tag VS WYSIWYG editor in order to achieve dynamic multi-color effect

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I need to create a web application with a feature
that the user is entering some text to a "text area" and the text need to be dynamically colored with multiple colors, according to some logic, via event that will be raised when the text is changing.
something similar to that: [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) just more basic (only multiple colors).

**Constrains:**

1. I don't want to use external sources or libraries.
2. no need for compatibility to old browsers.
3. I am using angular 2 with type script.

**Options:**

I did a research and (i think) i found 2 ways to achieve that result:

1. write my own version of [WYSIWYG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG) (btw, is that approach can be implemented dynamically?)
2. use the `<code>` tag and set `contenteditable="true"` with multiple spans as it is explained in that marked answer: [Multicolor Text Highlighting in a Textarea or Text Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845813/multicolor-text-highlighting-in-a-textarea-or-text-input)

According to your experience what is the approach that is more suitable for that task?

Or maybe I am missing something and there is a better approach?

I just need guidance in what way to go.

Comment: You've given two options, but Option 2 just sounds like a description of how you would implement Option 1.

Comment: Despite of your effort, you won't achieve as stable solutions as external sources are. Using a third part software is part of software development... Angular is a third-part software. Look at: [Froala](https://github.com/froala/angular-froala-wysiwyg) or [TinyMCE](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/integrations/angular2/)

Comment: @Hitmands, i am totally agree with you, "text editor" behavior can be very tricky, but my goal is to learn angular that is why i prefer to do it myself, nobody will use this app except me.