# Change Text Color if match found automatically JavaScript|HTML

Tags: javascript, html

i have a textarea where i want to change color automatically

for example : this is my pen my friend

as soon as i enter the above text the keyword=pen should become green color and 
keyword=freind should become red as soon it matches

How do i achieve this thing

code is working but half working

```
function changeText() 
{
        document.getElementById("text").style.color ="green";
}
</script>
```

Another Code i have But not Working

```
 var str = 'Connect'; 
    var value = str.includes('Connect'); 

    if(value==str)
    {
        document.getElementById("text").style.color ="green"; 
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("text").style.color ="red";
    }
```

Comment: simple debug statement: `console.log(value, str, value==str)`

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do this in a textarea or text input. Any CSS text-related property will affect the whole text within the the textarea/input, not just a word.

see for more info: [Multicolor Text Highlighting in a Textarea or Text Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845813/multicolor-text-highlighting-in-a-textarea-or-text-input)

Comment: You could if you spoofed a textbox with a standard div. Like how selectize.js spoofs select boxes.

Comment: the guy is a novice, would be difficult for him to get this is I suppose

Comment: Definitely. And not our job to code out for them. Your statement is correct though so I'll plus that.

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll need to detect changes on the text area. Look into [`element.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and the [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) event. Then inspect the text from the text area. You have bunch of options for this, but the easiest one is [`string.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes). If it returns `true`, call your function to turn the text green.

Comment: as i am new to javascript can anyone provide demo code