# Javascript textarea apply style.color from current location

Tags: javascript, colors, textarea

Is there a way to not apply style.color on the whole textarea but from current key?
For instance, "Hello -specialBlueColor- Welcome to my world -specialYellowColor- hope you like it", and define the keywords as specialBlueColor = some specific hex color, or word, and apply them as typing.

I only know how to append style.color on the whole textarea but not specifically as described.

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845813/multicolor-text-highlighting-in-a-textarea-or-text-input).
This is not possible as the "color " property will affect the whole text. The provided link will give you a workaround though.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The standard HTML textarea cannot be modified, but you can always create your own text-editing container with a little fine-tuning as demonstrated below, to achieve the colorful effects you desire:

The CSS:

```
.Con {
    overflow:auto; 
    width:500px; 
    height:100px; 
    border:1px solid black; 
    resize:vertical;
}
    
green {color:green;}
    
blue {color:blue;}
    
red {color:red;}
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="Con" spellcheck="false" contenteditable="true">You can 
edit <red>the</red> contents of <blue>this</blue> fake 
colorful textarea...
</div>
```